# Floating point number and range of floating point numbers that can be represented by a string

Tags: floating-point, discrete-mathematics

refer to the string of bits 010011110110

```
We also assume that when the number is stored as a floating point (real) number, 6 of the 12 bits are reserved for the mantissa (or significand)

If the string represents a floating point number, what is this (smallest) number?
```

and

```
Find the range (or interval) of floating point numbers that could be represented by the same string.

value=(-1)^s (1+m/26 )^{e-24} is what I think I need in order to solve one of the,
```

These are the last two questions I have for an assessment due on Thursday 28th, I've completed all the other questions and at this point in time I have no idea if any of them are right and I'm just stuck on these question. I have no Idea why I have to do a computer science class as a networking major but it's killing me.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221206/floating-point-number-mantissa-exponent

Answer (score 0):

Since the base is 2 and the mantissa is 6 and assuming a 12 digit precision, according to [wikipedia on floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), I believe the range would be 100000 * 2^011111 to 011111 * 2^011111 or rather -32*2^31 to 31*2^31, where as the smallest value would be 1*2^100000 or rather 1*2^-32.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try and work out how you did that but it's just well outside anything I know. I know the smallest number will always be all zeros and the largets all ones. but where you pulled the 32 and 31 from i'm lost

Answer (score 0):

`6 of the 12 bits are reserved for the mantissa` and `value=(-1)^s (1+m/26 )^{e-24}`

The second one should logically be  `value=(-1)^s (1+m/2^6 )^{e-2^4}`

So let's go you have:

- 1 bit of sign s
- 1 implied leading one + 6 bits m (=0 to: 63) for significand (a total of 7 bits)
- 5 bits remaining for the exponent (e=0 to 31)

so the maximum significand value is `1+63/64`, that is `127/64`, `(2^7-1)/2^6`, `2-2^-6`

and the maximum exponent is `31-16=15`.

So the maximum number is `(2-2^-6)*2^15=2^16-2^9=65536-512=65024`

The minimum number is -65024.

**EDIT**

Now, I'm not sure i completely understand the question with same string...

If the question is which interval will be rounded to the same float, then

- it depends on rounding method
- it depends on exponent

If we presume that numbers are rounded to nearest float, every number in the interval `(f-ulp(f)/2,f+ulp(f)/2)` will be rounded to same float f.

if f=(-1)^s*(1+m/2^6)*2^(e-2^4), then the ulp(f) is 2^(e-2^4-6), so you get the asnwer. Inclusion of bounds of the interval depends on detailed rounding method (round to nearest even).

For the minimum positive value, I don't know...

- Either the smallest exponent is reserved for representing denormal numbers and zero.
- or maybe there is no zero in this representation...

In first case, with denormals, min exponent is `1-16=-15`, and minimum positive value is `2^-6*2^-15 = 2^-21`

In second case, minimum exponent is `0-16=-16`, and minimum positive value is `1*2^-16`.

Third case, if only zero is a special case, and no denormals, min value is `(1+2^-6)*2^-16`